# Lock between N Processes in Promela

Tags: verification, model-checking, promela, spin

I am trying to model one of my project in promela for model checking. In that, i have N no of nodes in network. So, for each node I am making a process. Something like this:

```
init {
byte proc;
atomic {
    proc = 0;
    do
    :: proc < N ->
        run node (q[proc],proc);
        proc++
    :: proc >= N ->
        break
    od
}
}
```

So, basically, here each 'node' is process that will simulate each node in my network. Now, Node Process has 3 threads which run parallelly in my original implementation and within these three threads i have lock at some part so that three threads don't access Critical Section at the same time. So, for this in promela, i have done something  like this:

```
proctype node (chan inp;byte ppid)
{
   run recv_A()
   run send_B()
   run do_C()
}
```

So here recv_A, send_B and do_C are the three threads running parallelly at each node in the network. Now, the problem is, if i put lock in recv_A, send_B, do_C using atomic then it will put lock lock over all 3*N processes whereas i want a lock such that the lock is applied over groups of three. That is, if process1's(main node process from which recv_A is made to run) recv_A is in its CS then only process1's send_B and do_C should be prohibited to enter into CS and not process2's recv_A, send_B, do_C. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your have several options, and all revolve around implementing some kind of *mutual exclusion algorithm among N processes*:

- [Peterson Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm)
- [Eisenberg & McGuire Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenberg_%26_McGuire_algorithm)
- [Lamport's bakery Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport%27s_bakery_algorithm)
- [Szymański's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szymanski%27s_Algorithm)
- ...

An implementation of the *Black & White Bakery Algorithm* is available [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2017/lesson04/optional04.tar.gz). Note, however, that these algorithms *-maybe with the exception of Peterson's one-* tend to be complicated and might make the verification of your system impractical.

**A somewhat simple** approach is to resort on the *Test & Set Algorithm* which, however, still uses `atomic` in the *trying section*. Here is an example implementation taken from [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2017/lesson05/exercises05.tar.gz).

```
bool lock = false;
int counter = 0;

active [3] proctype mutex()
{
  bool tmp = false;

trying:
  do
    :: atomic {
       tmp = lock;
       lock = true;
       } ->
       if
          :: tmp;
          :: else -> break;
       fi;
  od;

critical:
    printf("Process %d entered critical section.\n", _pid);
    counter++;
    assert(counter == 1);
    counter--;

exit:
    lock = false;
    printf("Process %d exited critical section.\n", _pid);

goto trying;
}

#define c0 (mutex[0]@critical)
#define c1 (mutex[1]@critical)
#define c2 (mutex[2]@critical)
#define t0 (mutex[0]@trying)
#define t1 (mutex[1]@trying)
#define t2 (mutex[2]@trying)
#define l0 (_last == 0)
#define l1 (_last == 1)
#define l2 (_last == 2)
#define f0 ([] <> l0)
#define f1 ([] <> l1)
#define f2 ([] <> l2)

ltl p1 { []   !(c0  &&  c1)  && !(c0 && c2) && !(c1 && c2)}
ltl p2 { []((t0 || t1 || t2) -> <> (c0 || c1 || c2)) }
ltl p3 {
        (f0 -> [](t0 -> <> c0))
        &&
        (f1 -> [](t1 -> <> c1))
        &&
        (f2 -> [](t2 -> <> c2))
        };
```

In your code, you should use a different `lock` variable for every group of `3` related threads. The lock contention would still happen at a global level, but some process working inside the *critical section* would not cause other processes to wait other than those who belong to the same thread group.

**Another idea** is that to exploit *channels* to achieve mutual exclusion: have each group of threads share a common **asynchronous** channel which initially contains one `token` message. Whenever one of these threads wants to access the critical section, it reads from the channel. If the `token` is not inside the channel, it waits until it becomes available. Otherwise, it can go forward in the critical section and when it finishes it puts the `token` back inside the *shared channel*.

```
proctype node (chan inp; byte ppid)
{
   chan lock = [1] of { bool };
   lock!true;

   run recv_A(lock);
   run send_B(lock);
   run do_C(lock);
};

proctype recv_A(chan lock)
{
    bool token;
    do
        :: true ->

            // non-critical section code
            // ...

            // acquire lock
            lock?token ->

            // critical section
            // ...

            // release lock
            lock!token

            // non-critical section code
            // ...
    od;
};

...
```

This approach might be the simplest to start with, so I would pick this one first. Note however that I have no idea on how that affects performance during verification time, and this might very well depend on how channels are internally handled by `Spin`. A complete code example of this solution can be found [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2017/lesson05/exercises05.tar.gz) in the file `channel_mutex.pml`.

To conclude, note that you might want to add *mutual exclusion*, *progress* and *lockout-freedom* `LTL` properties to your model to ensure that it behaves correctly. An example of the definition of these properties is available [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2017/lesson04/lesson04.pdf) and a code example is available [here](http://www.patricktrentin.com/teaching/fm2017/lesson04/exercises04.tar.gz).